# How Nullable<T> = null works?

Tags: c#

```
int? num = null;
```

How does it work under the hood? I always assumed Nullable is a class and today I was debugging and was surprised to see it's a struct. I checked the source code and found this implicit operator:

```
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) 
{
    return new Nullable<T>(value);
}
```

It's obviously not the answer here since null is not an int. In addition the constructor is this:

```
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public Nullable(T value) 
{
    this.value = value;
    this.hasValue = true;
}
```

So the constructor is not called either.

Is compiler using some synthetic sugar here?

Comment: http://alexey-anufriev.com/blog/can-c-struct-be-assigned-to-null/

Comment: Yeah a class doesn't make any sense, it could be null! however @mjwills link says it all `int? = null` is really  `Nullable<int> value = new Nullable<int>`

Comment: @mjwills Thanks. That clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type? t = null;
```

is recognized by the compiler and replaced with `type? t = new type?()`, which invokes the default constructor which in turn sets the object to all zeros. The property `HasValue` is backed by a `boolean` variable such that `false` is the correct initial value in this case.

In just about every place, these constructions are treated as though they were references to a an object of type `type`. In order to observe they aren't you would need a mutable `struct`. The compiler knows about `type?` in quite a few ways including checking the `HasValue` property when boxing and boxing to a `null` or a boxed `type`. If you manage to get a boxed `type?` the unboxer should be able to handle it, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get a boxed `type?` anymore unless you're writing `extern` functions.

Comment: Wow pretty clever.

Comment: "In just about every place, these constructions are treated as though they were references to a an object of type type" - no, they're value type values, and handled as value types everywhere. Additionally, a value of type (say) `int?` is *not* treated as if it were `int`. You can't call the methods from `int` on it, for example. My guess is that you're referring to the lifted operators, but that's a long way from "in just about every place" IMO.